# Double expansion of shell variable

Tags: shell, variables, unix, expansion

I have a table which contains an env variable and I need to fetch the variable's value and export for another java utility from within the shell script:

```
    command="SELECT param_value FROM tableX WHERE param_name='ABCD';"
    #This param_value is ${PATHX} and PATHX is /home/users/pathx

    PARAM_VALUE=`sqlplus -s $CONN_STRING <<- END
    SET head off;
    set feedback off;
    ${command}
    exit;
    END`

    echo ${PARAM_VALUE} | grep -q "ERROR"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
            echo "Failed in fetching param_value "
            exit 1
    else
            #Trimming the value fetched from DB
            PARAM_VALUE=`echo "${PARAM_VALUE}" | tr -d " " | tr -d "\n"`
            echo "Value fetched from DB=${PARAM_VALUE}" 
            #This prints ${PATHX}
            export PATH_VALUE="${PARAM_VALUE}" 
            #This is exporting PATH_VALUE as ${PATHX} instead of /home/users/pathx - WHICH IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            #If I put directly export PATH_VALUE="${PATHX}", it exports the value correctly as /home/users/pathx
    fi
```

After searching for options, I have tried various options like below but failed:

```
export PATH_VALUE="${PARAM_VALUE}"
export PATH_VALUE=`eval echo "\$${PARAM_VALUE}"`
export PATH_VALUE=$(eval \$$PARAM_VALUE)
export PATH_VALUE=${$PARAM_VALUE}
export PATH_VALUE=${!PARAM_VALUE}
export PATH_VALUE=`echo ${PARAM_VALUE}`
export PATH_VALUE=`expr ${PARAM_VALUE}`
```

Please suggest what can be done in this case to export the actual expanded value - /home/users/pathx.

Comment: Please do not use \` backticks. Use `$(...)` instead. `export PATH_VALUE=${!PARAM_NAME}` should work, did you test it? Do not `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` just the command `if echo "$PARAM_VALUE" | grep -q "ERROR"; then`. Use http://shellcheck.net for catching common mistakes.

Comment: Where are you calling the java app from within your script? A script can never modify the environment of its parent process. So any environment variables you set in you script are lost when the script exits. (that's also why the only place environment variables are set and exported for your current shell is in the run config file like `.bashrc` or `.profile`, etc..) So if you are not calling the java app from your script your environment changes are meaningless.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I had tried with $(...) as well. The  ```export PATH_VALUE=${!PARAM_NAME}``` did not work, I had tested it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am calling the java app from within the script. I have not put the code of java invocation in my question as it was out of scope of my main problem.

Comment: @thanasisp, thanks for pointing out, it was a copy-paste mistake, fixed the question.

Comment: So what does `echo "Value fetched from DB=${PARAM_VALUE}"` output?

Comment: @KamilCuk, it outputs ${PATHX}

Comment: So the query response is the literal `${PATHX}` which is already declared in your script/environment and you want to expand it?

Comment: @thanasisp, yes the query response is ${PATHX} and this is an environment variable which I need to expand.

Comment: @Ashish : `${!PARAM_NAME}` is a bash-construct. That's why it does not work in your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes the query response is ${PATHX} and this is an environment variable which I need to expand.

You could use `eval`, but `eval` is evil, if the value is exported, do a safe `envsubst`:

```
PARAM_VALUE=$(envsubst <<<"$PARAM_VALUE")
```

Comment: Maybe you want to point out (since `envsubst` is not available on every platform) that an alternative would be to switch to `bash` or `zsh`, which have builtin ways to deal with this problem.

Comment: `which have builtin way` och, I am out of ideas. What would be a builtin way in bash? I can only think of ideas around eval, like `sh -c "echo $PARAM_VALUE"` or `source <(echo "echo $PARAM_VALUE")` etc.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `${(P)PARAM_VALUE}` in Zsh. Or did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: The _content_ of the variable is `${PATHX}` _including_ literal `$` and `{` `}`. The following `PATHX=something; PARAM_VALUE='${PATHX}'; echo ${(P)PARAM_VALUE}` prints some number, not the content of `PATHX`. The following `PATHX=something; PARAM_VALUE='PATHX'; echo ${(P)PARAM_VALUE}` would "work", but that's not the problem at hand.

Comment: Get it now. Strange design. Alternatively, one could get rid of these `${}` characters, as LeadingEdger suggested in his response, but who knows what other variants of this format they use in their database....

Answer (score 2):

For it to work the way you expect, the sqlplus query response should be `PATHX` instead of `${PATHX}`. One way to fix it is to replace

```
PARAM_VALUE=`echo "${PARAM_VALUE}" | tr -d " " | tr -d "\n"`
```

with

```
PARAM_VALUE=`echo "${PARAM_VALUE}" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r'`
```